# WPF Capture MouseMove

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, mouse

I have a mouse move event that captures the position on a canvas and displays with a tooltip. The issue is after some time the tooltip goes away and the event doesn't fire. I've uploaded code for the move event. TT is the tooltip name.

```
 private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {

        tt.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
        tt.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
        tt.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;
        tt.Content = "X-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + "\n" + "Y-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y;
    }
```

Comment: This is not the normal use of a tool-tip. It might be better to add a custom control that follows the mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, this is not an ideal usage for a `ToolTip`, but given that your requirements seem to be some kind of quick test, you may as well continue along the same vein. As such, you can try just setting the `ToolTip.IsOpen` property to `true` to keep the `ToolTip` open:

```
private void Canvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    tt.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Relative;
    tt.HorizontalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + 10;
    tt.VerticalOffset = e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y + 10;
    tt.Content = "X-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).X + "\n" + "Y-Coordinate: " + e.GetPosition((IInputElement)sender).Y;
    tt.IsOpen = true;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for isOpen. Im using this as a way to check positions but I will take your advice and build a custom control. Thanks